# Angular bindings not updating within $interval and $http

Tags: angularjs

I've tried different variations of `$apply()` and `$digest()` to no avail.

The binding should update once the courier is no longer null with the name of the courier, however nothing is happening.  I've been able to log the name of the courier when they are assigned, however the dom element is not updating.  I'm using jade and compiling to html without any issues elsewhere in the application.  I'm also calling the `refreshDelivery` function immediately prior to rendering the view shown below, which is working correctly.

app.js:

```
    var storeController = require('./controllers/controller');



var storeApp = angular.module('AngularStore', ['ngRoute']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/store', { 
      templateUrl: 'views/store.html',
      controller: storeController }).
    when('/products/:productSku', {
      templateUrl: 'views/product.html',
      controller: storeController }).
    when('/cart', { 
      templateUrl: 'views/shoppingCart.html',
      controller: storeController }).
    when('/delivery', {
      templateUrl: 'views/delivery.html',
      controller: storeController }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/store' });
}])
  .controller('storeController', storeController);
```

controller.js:

```
      function storeController($scope, $routeParams, $http, $interval, DataService) {

  // get store and cart from service
  $scope.store = DataService.store;
  $scope.cart = DataService.cart;
  $scope.mapInit = DataService.mapInit;

  // use routing to pick the selected product
  if ($routeParams.productSku != null) {
    $scope.product = $scope.store.getProduct($routeParams.productSku);
  }

  // var locationOptions = {
  //   enableHighAccuracy: true,
  //   timeout: 5000,
  //   maximumAge: 0
  // }

  // navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
  //   var mapOptions = {
  //     center: { lat: pos.coords.latitude, lng: pos.coords.longitude},
  //     zoom: 13
  //   };
  //   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  //       mapOptions);
  // });

  $scope.search = function(query){
    var responseObject;
    console.log('in search');
    $http({
      url:'/apiCall', 
      data: {data: '/products?keyword=' + query + '&latlong=36.125962,-115.211263'},
      method: 'POST'
    })
    .then(function(response){
      responseObject = response.data.data;
      responseObject.forEach(function(data){
        var productData = {
          sku: data.Id.SkuPartNumber,
          productName: data.Description.Name,
          desc: data.Description.BrandName,
          price: data.Price.DisplayPrice,
          url: data.Description.ImageURL,
          storeNumber: data.StoreNumber
        }
        var temp = new product(productData)
        $scope.store.addProduct(temp)
      });
    });
  }

  $scope.getDeliveryQuote = function(){
    var responseObject;
    $scope.quoted = false;
    var storeNumber = $scope.cart.items[0].storeNumber
    console.log($scope.cart.items[0].storeNumber);
    var url = '/delivery_quote?drop_off_latlong=36.125962,-115.211263&pickup_store_number='.concat(storeNumber);
    $http({
      url: '/apiCall/',
      data: {data: url},
      method: 'POST'
    })
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.quoted = true;
      console.log(response.data.id);
      $scope.quote = response.data.fee;
      $scope.quoteId = response.data.id
    })
  }

  $scope.submitOrder = function(){
    var url = '/submit_delivery?drop_off_latlong=36.125962,-115.211263&pickup_store_number=0001709&manifest=puppies&phone_number=555-555-5555&quote_id=' + $scope.quoteId + '&customer_name=Arnold';
    $http({
      url: '/apiCall/',
      data: {data: url},
      method: 'POST'
    })
    .then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
      $scope.deliveryId = response.data.id;
      $scope.refreshDelivery();
      window.location.href='/#/delivery';
    })
  }

  $scope.refreshDelivery = function() {
    var url = '/update?delivery_id='.concat($scope.deliveryId);
    var promise = $interval(function(){
      $http({
        url: '/apiCall/',
        data: {data: url},
        method: 'POST'
      })
      .then(function(resp) {
        $scope.update = resp.data;
        if (resp.data.courier){
          $scope.update.courier = resp.data.courier;
          console.log($scope.update.courier.name);//outputs correct name
          $scope.$apply();
        }
        //stops when complete
        if ($scope.update.complete){
          $interval.cancel(promise);
        }
      })
    }, 5000 );
  }
}

module.exports = storeController;
```

Jade before compiling to HTML:

Partial:

```
p.text-info {{update.courier.name}} is on their way!
```

Default:

```
html(ng-app='AngularStore')
  head
    // includes for jquery, angular, and bootstrap 
    script(src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false")
    script(src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') 
    script(rel='stylesheet' href='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    script(src='bower_components/angular/angular.js')
    script(src='bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js')
    // includes for the Angular Store app
    script(src='/js/main.js')     
    script(src='/js/bundle.js')     
    link(href='/styles/main.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
    |   
  body
    .container-fluid
      .row-fluid
        .span10.offset1
          h1.well
            a(href='default.html')
            |                     Angular Store

          div(ng-view='')
```

Comment: Your javascript looks correct (you don't need to trigger a `$digest` when using `$http`), so your markup must be where the issue is - can you show the rest of it?

Comment: In your success callback, the first lines set the `$scope.update` and conditionally the `$scope.update.courier.name`. Since you are already setting `$scope.update` to `resp.data`, would that not implicitly set `$scope.update.courier.name` to `resp.data.courier.name` if `resp.data.courier` is set? I think that is your problem, you are not setting the object, but the property.

Comment: sounds more like a scope problem. Is the html shown in a directive with isolated scope?

Comment: @GPicazo  I declared it specifically because the implicit definition was not working.

Comment: @charlietfl  I'm only using one controller for the whole app, and showing one function.  $scope.update has not been used anywhere else.

Comment: @EdHinchliffe  I know I shouldn't have to, however given other answers to somewhat similar questions, I thought I would cover those bases.  I've included my default jade file, however bindings are working without issue elsewhere in the application.

Comment: I don't know jade...is partial being delivered as full html and angular expression still intact? Easy to inspect ajax request and inspect response body

Comment: @charlietfl The default+partial are jiving correctly.  Here is the resulting html for the binding: <p class="text-info ng-binding ng-scope"> is on their way!</p>

Comment: scope problem somehwere ...you sure the html is inside that controller?

Comment: @charlietfl 'ng-scope' is included in classes with bindings throughout the application, and I'm using ng-route to declare the controller.  Unfortunately I can't detect any difference in what is working and what is not.  I wouldn't be surprised if it was a jade issue, I'm new to angular and will probably not be using jade with angular again.

Comment: that's why I mentioned inspecting the actual response body of ajax ... can see exactly what is sent although I think it is OK or `ng-binding` wouldn't be applied

Comment: @charlietfl The response body is not the issue, as seen by the correct logging of data.

Comment: i meant response of the template ajax call...still think it is ok though...never hurts to check

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, I'm confused, how do I check that?  I thought you meant my call to my server from the model.

Comment: unless you are compiling templates into js files or script tags that are loaded in page...each template request would be ajax requests which can be inspected in browser dev tools newtork

Comment: @charlietfl  when I open the file from the request it looks llike: "{{update.courier.name}} is on their way!"

Also, I very much appreciate your help, I've been struggling with this for way, way, way to long

Comment: It's not a jade issue as far as I can see - that should work fine. It must be a scope problem - what context is the javascript running in? Is it a controller somewhere? If so where is that controller in the DOM (i.e. `ng-controller` or a custom directive somewhere).

Comment: I agree there is a scope problem and we can't see enough to troubleshoot it

Comment: @EdHinchliffe  I've updated with the full controller and app.  I'm also using a factory however it does not seem relevant.

Comment: @charlietfl updated with more info

Answer (score 1):

I found a way around the `$scope` issue by creating a separate controller to handle updates.

app:

```
var storeController = require('./controllers/storeController'),
    deliveryController = require('./controllers/deliveryController');



var storeApp = angular.module('AngularStore', ['ngRoute']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/store', { 
      templateUrl: 'views/store.html',
      controller: storeController }).
    when('/products/:productSku', {
      templateUrl: 'views/product.html',
      controller: storeController }).
    when('/cart', { 
      templateUrl: 'views/shoppingCart.html',
      controller: storeController }).
    when('/delivery/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'views/delivery.html',
      controller: deliveryController }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/store' });
}])
  .controller('storeController', storeController);
```

new deliveryController

```
function deliveryController($scope, $routeParams, $http, $interval) {
  console.log($routeParams);

  var refreshDelivery = function(id) {
    var url = '/update?delivery_id='.concat(id);
    var promise = $interval(function(){
      $http({
        url: '/apiCall/',
        data: {data: url},
        method: 'POST'
      })
      .then(function(resp) {
        $scope.update = resp.data;
        if (resp.data.courier){
          $scope.update.courier = resp.data.courier;
          console.log($scope.update.courier.name);//outputs correct name
        }
        //stops when complete
        if ($scope.update.complete){
          $interval.cancel(promise);
        }
      })
    }, 5000 );
  }
  refreshDelivery($routeParams.id);
}

module.exports = deliveryController;
```